# How can I use the pipeline output from different commands inside a custom bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting, pipe

I have this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This command removes the last "\n" (line feed) character from the file specified as parameter
#
# Params:
# $1 [FILE_NAME] - the name of the file to trim

if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
        echo "perlrmlastlf - A command utility which uses perl to remove the last \"\n\" (line feed) character inside a file"
        echo $'\r'
        echo "perlrmlastlf: missing FILE_NAME"
        echo "Usage: perlrmlastlf [FILE_NAME]"
        echo $'\r'
        exit;
fi

if [[ ! -f $1 ]]; then
        echo "perlrmlastlf - A command utility which uses perl to remove the last \"\n\" (line feed) character inside a file"
        echo $'\r'
        echo "perlrmlastlf: wrong FILE_NAME $1: No such file"
        echo "Usage: perlrmlastlf [FILE_NAME]"
        echo $'\r'
        exit;
fi

FILE=$1
TMP_FILE="$FILE.tmp.perlrmlastlf"
perl -0 -pe 's/\n\Z//' $FILE > $TMP_FILE

mv $TMP_FILE $FILE
```

Now, I can actually use it only with a valid filename as the parameter, but what if I want to make it receive the output from a pipe and use that instead of $1 [FILE_NAME]? Like this:

```
user:machine ~$ cat file.txt | pcregrep -o "some pattern" | perlrmlastlf
user:machine ~$ # output of `cat file.txt | pcregrep -o "some pattern"` but without last \n, if present
```

And make `perlrmlastlf` receive the pipeline output and use it and then output back to the console the matched string without the last \n char

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way, but it's early...

```
if (( $# > 0 )); then
    # the "-i" option takes care of writing to a tmp file and 
    # overwriting the original file
    perl -0 -i -pe 's/\n\Z//' "$1"
else
    # read from stdin and write to stdout
    perl -0 -pe 's/\n\Z//'
fi
```

you'll need to remove the `[[ $1 == "" ]]` check, and put the `[[ ! -f $1 ]]` check inside the "true" block of my if statement.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `$#` variable?

Comment: Nevermind, I have found it here http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html